# Dojo dgrid updating a row

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I have a dgrid that populates from a dojo/request:

```
var TrackableMem = declare([Memory, Trackable]);
var store = new TrackableMem({
    data : resp.results
});
```

This grid has a few columns that are textboxes. When they are changed, I would like to confirm the user actually wants to edit them:

```
grid.on("dgrid-datachange", function(evt) {
    if(!confirm("change this field?")) {
         // revert cell value back to the old one.
         grid.get("collection").get(evt.cell.row.id).notes = evt.oldValue;
         grid.refresh();
    } else {
        // do ajax call here.....
    }
}
```

This does not work, the new updated value stays there, but when I run the same exact thing in the developer console it does work:

```
grid.get("collection").get(0).notes = "testing";
grid.refresh();
```

Any ideas? evt.cell.row.id & evt.oldValue are correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to manually revert the data in the `dgrid-datachange` handler since the values haven't been persisted yet.

This is done on purpose so that you can cancel the update. In your case you could do:

`grid.on("dgrid-datachange", function(evt) {
    if(!confirm("change this field?")) {
         evt.preventDefault();
    } else {
        // do ajax call here.....
    }
}`

You can read more about this [in the offical docs](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/doc/components/mixins/Editor.md) and [this Github ticket](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/912).

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!